# How to replace part of string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, str-replace

I want to replace all the :

```
xmlns="http://xml.blablabla"
```

and

```
 xmlns:something="xxxx"
```

for a white space from a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ruby
str.sub!(/xmlns=.+?"/, ' ')
```

Comment: This works, but only for the first occurrence... how can I make it for every occurrenceof the regex?

Answer (score 1):

[String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185) is your friend:

```
my_string = '<Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply xmlns="http://xml.blablabla">'
my_string.sub(/\s.+$/, " >")
# => "<Fare_MasterPricerCalendarReply >"
```

Comment: That erases everything in my string... =S

Comment: Yes, sorry... But @Radu answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `xmlns="[^"]*"`, it matches `xmlns="http://xml.blablabla"`, then replace match with empty string.